# How to get record's primary key value on saving in manual mode?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, google-app-maker

I have a model in **manual save mode** and a form in **create** mode. Once I add details and click on submit it should create the record and 
alert something like 'Your request is registered with id=7' where id is the id (primary key).

Note the primary key is in auto increment and generated dynamically.

In manual save mode I am using **saveChanges** to save the record but seeing error:

> SEVERE: Record RecordKey{key=private$2, model
>   key=1ymdoCYoHKEGpumlXveKKZh_57jUjd9OY|7LyXBUY46K9Jl6GRCy1DeL32kXmnGHis}
>   already deleted.Failed: getProperty   at  Object.
>   (UserCreationRequest:12:37)   at  createUCR (UserCreationRequest:11:19)
>     at 
>   UserCreationRequest.Container.UserCreationRequestPanel.UserCreationRequestPanelFooter.UserCreationRequestPanelSubmitButton.onClick:1:1

(In error 12:37 points to record._key)

**Code:** (executed OnClick of submit button)

```
   widget.datasource.saveChanges(function(record) {
   alert('Your request is registered with id='+record._key);
   }
```

Can someone please advise how to get the primary key on saving in manual mode?

Additional Info Reference:

The above code has worked for me in some other place for some other model. But not working for the current model, is it because the current model has a relation?

I added a new datasource in the Datasources section of the current model
and by using that its working fine. But why is not working fine with the original one?

Also FYI, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46067509/google-app-maker-record-key-value) is a similar issue but it did not help as it's a different approach. I'm keen to save using the widget itself.

Comment: More Meta comment: I'm not sure this should have the [google-apps-script] tag. App Maker does use Apps Script as a back-end but the functions seem very different. *Also, I want to play with App Maker so bad.*

Comment: @chris There's a free 14 day trial. Why don't you go and play?

Comment: From the documention I see that saveChanges does not have a callback function with record however it had worked for me in some other place. Anyways if not then can someone please suggest how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

First, we need to understand that the **create mode** is not the same as the normal mode. Having that clear, we can do the following:

Assuming the datasource name is MYDATASOURCE, the form datasource should be MYDATASOURCE(create). Then, on the **onClick** event of the **submit** button widget inside the **insert form**, use this:

```
widget.datasource.createItem(function(record){
  app.datasources.MYDATASOURCE.saveChanges(function(){
    console.log(record._key);
  });
});
```

Comment: Just to make sure we are on the same page, by create mode I mean that the datasource is in create mode i.e MYDATASOURCENAME(create) is set for the form.

I got record._key = null with your code. I think it's because since the datasource  is in manual mode the create item creates the record but it dosen't saves it to the datasource.

Comment: @abhishek186 Yes. So basically, the form will have the MYDATASOURCENAME(create) as the datasource. When you click the submit button, first you have to create the item on the (create) datasource and once the item is created, you need to save changes on the non(create) datasouce, i,e MYDATASOURCENAME only. It works for me just fine.

Comment: Not working for me yet. When I print record._key,  it shows null value. When I print a field name other than the primary key for eg record.FirstName, I get the value. So it looks like the record is created but without a key until it is saved. Inside saveChanges we are printing the record but the record is retrurned by createItem which does not contain any key.

Comment: @abhishek186 there is something wrong with your setup. It works great for me in different projects. Good luck.

Comment: In this case I would like to confirm from other users. Probably there is some different setting if its working for you and not working for me.